# Creating an arbitrary hierarchy of characters

Tags: ruby, string, compare

Let's say I have 4 characters, A, P, B, N. I want to be able to compare them such that:

A > P > B > N > A

How would this be accomplished in Ruby?

Comment: So, "greater than" is not transitive operator in your case? How do A and B compare then?

Comment: No, I guess this is a "circular" hierarchy.

Comment: Uhm... how can you establish whether A is or not > of N, if it is in a circular hierarchy?

Comment: I guess that the idea resembles the "rock-paper-scissors" relations then, but then the word "compare" is misleading.

Comment: Comparison is Binary... so it depends which you're comparing it to.

Comment: Ok, but how can you compare, f.e., A and B?

Comment: @ProGNOMers I won't. I will throw an exception if two non-neighbors are compared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, it seems that you are *not* trying to put these elements in *order*, but rather define some binary relation between *some* of them. It's possible to do that in Ruby in many ways, depending on how you intend to use that relation later.

The simplest one is just to define ordered pairs of related elements:

```
MAP = [
  ['A', 'P'],
  ['P', 'B'],
  ['B', 'N'],
  ['N', 'A']
]
```

And then use it whenever you need to "compare" two elements.

```
def beats? one, other
  MAP.member?([one, other])
end

beats? 'A', 'B'
# => false 
beats? 'A', 'P'
# => true 
beats? 'N', 'A'
# => true
```

PS. You can generate the map from a string using something like

```
MAP = 'APBNA'.chars.each_cons(2).to_a
```

Comment: A map maps better to a hash than to an array.

Comment: True, except when you need an element to "beat" more than one other element. Anyway, let's leave that as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions is to create a class with, for example, `character` and `weight` or something. And implement `<=>` operator (method) in it.

Don't forget to include `Comparable` mixin into this class.

```
class ComparableCharacter
  include Comparable
  attr_accessor :character, :weight

  def <=>(another)
    weight <=> another.weight
  end
end
```

Comment: You're violating the Ruby conventions. It should be snake_case, not camelCase when it comes to variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "APBN"
h = {};(0...a.size).each{|i| h[a[i].chr] = i}
b = ['A','P','A','N', 'B','P']
b.sort_by{|t| h[t] }
```

Of course this can not work with your example as you have a bad ordering - you can never have A > P > A, but at least it shows you how to sort according to an order you want.

Comment: Instead of creating a temporary map, you could use `Array#index` in `sort_by`.

Comment: @MladenJablanović are you sure the performance will not suffer if you implement it that way?

Comment: By all means, but the implementation will be simpler. :) Also, another idea: `Hash['APBN'.chars.with_index.to_a]`

Answer (score 0):

If someone can be interested, this is my proposal (ternary comparison - because **comparison is not a binary operation!!!**):

```
class RockPaperScissors

  ITEMS = %W(A P B N)

  def self.compare(item, other_item)
    new(item).compare other_item
  end


  def initialize(item)

    # input validations?

    @item = item
  end

  def compare(other_item)

    # input validations?

    indexes_subtraction = ITEMS.index(@item) - ITEMS.index(other_item)

    case indexes_subtraction
    when 1, -1
      - indexes_subtraction
    else
      indexes_subtraction <=> 0
    end

  end

end

require 'test/unit'
include MiniTest::Assertions

assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('A', 'A'), 0
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('P', 'P'), 0
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('B', 'B'), 0
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('N', 'N'), 0
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('A', 'P'), 1
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('P', 'A'), -1
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('P', 'B'), 1
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('B', 'P'), -1
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('B', 'N'), 1
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('N', 'B'), -1
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('N', 'A'), 1
assert_equal RockPaperScissors.compare('A', 'N'), -1
```

---

### EXPLANATION

Equality: **(A, A)** comparison

1. Indexes: iA: 0; iA: 0
2. iA - iA = 0
3. A is equal to A, so we could return 0

Majority: **(A, P)**

1. Indexes: iA: 0; iP: 1
2. iA - iP = -1
3. A > P, so we must obtain 1; we can use the `-` function: `- (-1) -> 1`

Minority: **(P, A)**

1. Indexes: iP: 1; iA: 0
2. iP - iA = 1
3. P < A, so we must obtain -1; we can use the `-` function: `- (1) -> -1`

Edge case 1: **(N, A)**

1. Indexes: iN: 3, iA: 0
2. iN - iA = 3
3. N > A, so we must obtain 1; we can use the `<=>` function: `(3 <=> 0) -> 1`

Edge case 2: **(A, N)**

1. Indexes: iA: 0, iN: 3
2. iA - iN = -3
3. A < N, so we must obtain -1; we can use the `<=>` function: `(3 <=> 0) -> 1`

The rest is refactoring: `0` can be converted to `0` with the `<=>` function.